# Alamofire not recognizing POST method and also the parameters

Tags: xcode, alamofire

I am using Alamofire in iOS 9 and am noticing that Alamofire is not sending the parameters to my PHP script in a POST method.

This is the PHP script:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
    echo '{"status": "error", "message" : "Only POST supported. You sent: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].'"}';
    return;
}

if (!isset($_POST['GENDER']) || !isset( $_POST['CHAR_COUNT_LOWER'] ) || !isset( $_POST['CHAR_COUNT_UPPER'] )) {
    echo '{"status": "error", "message" : "Minimum parameters not set."}';
    return;
}
```

Then, when firing my Alamofire POST request, I get the message:

> swift:55 fetchData(_:completionHandler:): Only
>   POST supported. You sent: GET

And, finally, this is my Alamofire request:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: ["CHAR_COUNT_LOWER":String(lowerValue), "CHAR_COUNT_UPPER":String(upperValue), "GENDER": String(gender!)] )
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                QL1(response.description)
                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    var result = [BabyNames]()
                    let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
                    if json["status"] == "error" {
                        QL4(json["message"])
                         completionHandler(babyNames: [], error: StoreError.CannotFetch("Could not retrieve baby names"))
                        return
                    }
 .......
```

I also tried changing the encoding to everything else but JSON, as my service does not take JSON as input.
It's a simple service that reads $_POST["param"]

Anything I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Still going crazy about it. Installed Charles to check what was the request coming out of my PC and here it goes:

[image]

EDIT 2:

Change the Alamofire request encoding to JSON:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters!, encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON )
```

Now I can see a GET and a POST request. The Post request:

> URL   http://example.com/backend/names/query_names.php
>   Status    Complete Response Code  301 Moved Permanently

Comment: Another comment is that I commented out the check on the REQUEST_METHOD and it then failed on the second condition, checking for the existence of the _POST parameters. Certainly this is expected. I would think Alamofire is also sending my parameters as _GET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found what the problem was.

My request URL was set to `http://server.com/api`

When I changed it to `http://www.server.com/api`

That got it working. I don't know honestly why that would happen and if that's something to do with the .httpaccess but that's it.